# Open a class page with an Intent

Tags: java, android

I am using Android Studio, and I want to open a class page with an intent.

My code currently looks like this

```
public class StartUpScreen extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.start_up_page);

    final ImageView MyImageView =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    final Animation Animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getBaseContext(), R.anim.startup);
    final Animation Animation2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getBaseContext(), R.anim.abc_fade_out);

    MyImageView.startAnimation(Animation);
    Animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            MyImageView.startAnimation(Animation2);
            finish();
            Intent a = new Intent(this,MainPage.class);
            startActivity(a);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });

}
```

}

All looks good, but my `Intent` has a red line from `(this,MainPage.class);` I have looked and tried changing it with no luck.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: The error showed says "Cannot resolve constructor 'Intent(anonymous android.view.animation.Animation.AnimationListener, java.lang.Class<someonecorporations.myapplication.MainPage>)"

Comment: Please post the code of the entire class.

Comment: Where did you call this? From an activity? It seems to be called from another that that ins't an Activity

Comment: @Raj try  `new Intent(StartUpScreen.this, MainPage.class)`

Comment: When you call `this` in the inner class, it refers to `AnimationListener`, not your activity.

Comment: @DeividiCavarzan it has resolved the problem, thanks.